# Detailed Explanation for Dense Rank Explanation

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to understand Dense rank function when multiple arguments were uses. Could some one help me in understanding with the below example or any other example?

Thanks a ton in Advance!

Calculated Column: DenseRank([Country],[Event Identifier])

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did this make sense San?

Comment: @ scsimon: Thank a ton. It is really helpful in understanding. :) :) :)

Comment: No worries @san I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Help Pages](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_ranking_functions.htm)

> DenseRank(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3...)
>
> Returns an integer value ranking of the values in the selected column.
>   The first argument is the column to be ranked. An optional argument is
>   a string determining whether to use an ascending (default)  or a
>   descending ranking.  For the highest value to retrieve rank 1, use the
>   argument "desc",  for the lowest value to retrieve rank 1, use "asc".
>
> Ties are given the same rank value and the highest ranking number 
>   equals the number of unique values in the column.
>
> Additional column arguments (optional) can be used when the column 
>   should be split into separately ranked categories.
>
> Examples:
>
> DenseRank([Sales])
>
> DenseRank([Sales], "desc", [Region])

So, in your example you are ranking the `Country` grouped by / partitioned by the `Even Identifier` with a default `"asc"` order. This is done alphabetically, thus, if we look at Interim 1 we will see 4 ranks, 1-4 since you have 4 countries for Interim 1, in alphabetical order (ascending). Each "group", which is the 3rd argument and in your case `Event Identifier`, will get a set of rankings from 1 - n where n is the number of distinct values. If you remove this argument, the entire data set will be ranked without consideration of `Event Identifier`